# Java automated testing of C++ GUI

Tags: java, testing, automation

Is it possible to run automation testing on a GUI that doesn't use pixels as references on where to click?

I want to be able to move the GUI window anywhere on the desktop that isn't in the exact pixel location and run the automation. I'm not sure how I would be able to get Java to 'see' the GUI how it is and acknowledge which buttons to click.

I haven't found anything that can actually run automation that isn't based on pixels.

Comment: why would you test an C++ GUI with java?

Comment: To simulate user input and the java.lang.Robot simulates mouse movements and keyboards without have to install anything extra.

Comment: `Robot` should not be used for testing. As long as the robot runs you can't use your mouse/keyboard. There are much better ways to test. Have a look at [this link](https://www.guru99.com/gui-testing.html) for more info

Comment: I understand that, no human would be on the test machine while it's running.